# How do I add a hex code to brushes on C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I use this code to change my background `t1.Background = Brushes.White;` and it's working but how do I do it with hex codes? Because `t1.Background = Brushes.#FF2463AE;` doesn't work. I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Thank You.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `BrushConverter`

```
t1.Background = (Brush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF2463AE"));
```

It would probably be best to create a single instance of the converter if you are doing many conversions.

Answer (score 3):

You could try it like this:

```
SolidColorBrush color = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#ffaacc"));
t1.Background = color;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
t1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x24, 0x63, 0xAE));
```

Or if you are going to use the same color multiple times, save the brush:

```
Brush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x24, 0x63, 0xAE));
t1.Background = myBrush;
```

Comment: I like the idea of creating the reusable brush but the Hex based parameters values for FromArgb seems over complicated for modern color value tools.